# If number is not multiple of 6 find remainder in PHP

Tags: php

Okay i will have a number from my database. This could be 3, 15 , 138 etc. Basically any number.

Now if the number is not a multiple of 6 i want to find out how many more until it becomes a multiple of 6.

So for instance if my number is 4, i want it to say you need 2 more to reach a multiple of 6.

How can i achieve this? Also when giving an answer could you please explain how the formula works.

I have tried this which someone suggested

```
                    $number = 4;

                    if($number % 6 != 0) {
                        echo $number += 6 - ($number % 6);
                    }
```

But this just prints 6 out

Comment: Don't use `+=` in `echo $number += 6` as that will modify the number. Just echo what's on the left of `+=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `+=` modifies `$number` by the value returned

```
echo $number += 6 - ($number % 6);
```

Results in: `4 += 6 - 4` or `$number = 6`

Should be

```
echo $number = 6 - ($number % 6);
```

Results in: `$number = 6 - 4` or `$number = 2`

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are backwards:

```
$number = 4;

if(6 % $number != 0) {
 echo (6 % $number) - 6;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1V5Rb